# Use of variables in kernel function using OpenCL

Tags: opencl

My code is as follows.
******* host code******

```
//some declarations
cl_mem Curr_domain = NULL;
cl_mem dMobj = NULL;

//created  check, AvgBlk of type structure domainBlock

// now creating buffers for above datatypes
dMobj = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, 
    dCount*sizeof(struct domainBlock), AvgBlk, &ret);
Curr_domain = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, dCount *
    sizeof(struct domainBlock), check, &ret);

//passed these 2 objects to the kernel

******* kernel code******

__kernel void calculateRms( __global struct domainBlock* dMobj, 
        __global struct domainBlock* Curr_domain )
{
    int l = get_global_id(0);
    int i=0;
    int iType=0;

    for(iType =0; iType<8;iType++)
    {
        if(iType==0)
        {
            Curr_domain = dMobj;
        }
    }
}
```

This gives me build failure error!

But if I initialize Curr_domain = dMobj; before the loop it won't. But I want to do this for 6 more times.So how can I fix this issue?

I'm using  Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 for executing this program.

Comment: What is build error message and the value of ret returned by clCreateBuffer API?

Comment: Well I doubt before or after the loop would have any sense. You are overwriting an argument pointer by another pointer. It is clearly not what you want.

Comment: Sorry Sagar! I've changed the code as Curr_domain = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, dCount *
    sizeof(struct domainBlock), NULL, &ret); then the clCreateBuffer API returns 0. and the error message is ERROR: Unable to build program!

igdfcl32.dll successfully completed build.
igdfcl32.dll successfully completed build.
Error, line 1085: compile failed. But in my code there are hardly 600 lines in host code and 200 lines in device code.

Comment: DarkZeros, I want a to write loop in which only one value is changing depending on the value of iType. So I have created one variable and passed to device and in that loop I'm overwriting an argument pointer by another pointer, so that I don't need to write it 8 times.